# Как делать масштабируемую HTML-верстку?

Tags: html, css

Есть [сайт](https://www.pari.ru/promo/basta/), на котором при увеличении или уменьшении масштаба страницы или ее разрешения верстка остается такой же, просто уменьшаются элементы сайта пропорционально разрешению страницы.

Как делается такая верстка? Какие темы нужно изучить для того, чтобы верстать такие макеты?

Comment: `media queries` в css

Comment: Медиазапросы - это для стандартной, немасштабируемой верстки

Comment: Вёрстка не остаётся такой же - например, для экранов менее 1000px там всё здорово перестраивается, как раз благодаря медиа-запросам. Можете открыть [стилевой файл](https://origin.pb06e2-resources.com/webStaticPB/promo/basta/index.62dc1faf.css) этого сайта и посмотреть - там полно медиа-запросов. Что касается "резинового" поведения некоторых элементов между брейкпоинтами - для этого нужно задавать размеры в процентах или vw.

Comment: Там все размеры заданы в REM

Answer (score 0):

1. делать при помощи vw - использовать формулу calc(100vw * исходный размер/разрешение макета).
   То есть например у вас есть макет на 1440px и только, есть элемент с высотой 100px.
   Вы пишите height: calc(100vw * 100/1440) и у вас пропорционально будет увеличиваться/уменьшатся элементы. И получается на мобильном уст-ве у вас будет мини версия десктопа. По вопросу я подразумеваю вы это имели виду?

если же не это имели виду, то :

2. Медиа запросы. Советую начинать с mobile first делать, что бы повысить скорость отображения у смартфонов
   @media (min-width: 768px) || @media (max-width: 1023px)

Comment: На примере все размеры заданы в REM, поэтому не могу понять, как там все масштабируется. Там при увеличении масштаба страницы со страницей ничего не происходит, она остается такой же.

Comment: @FrontEnder007 Единица rem задаёт размер относительно размера шрифта элемента <html>. Смотря пример можно увидеть что у html, body{ font-size: .052vw;}, то есть он уменьшается и увеличивается в зависимости от разрешения экрана. Значит и rem будет действовать так же. Почитайте про эту единицу измерения и думаю поймете как все работает на сайте примера.

Comment: если трудно переводить пиксели в rem то есть множество калькуляторов, которые это делают за вас

Answer (score 0):

Можно юзать bootstrap [bootstrap-5](https://getbootstrap.com/)

Или @media (min-width: ...px)